# How to add the real hostname in the beginning of Linux cli command

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, perl

we have redhat servers - 7.2

the following output from sar print all relevant details as the following

```
sar -p -d 1 1


07:16:35 PM       DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util
07:16:36 PM       sda     13.00      0.00    120.00      9.23      0.04      3.08      1.38      1.80
07:16:36 PM vg_livecd-lv_root     15.00      0.00    120.00      8.00      0.05      3.07      1.27      1.90
07:16:36 PM vg_livecd-lv_swap      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
07:16:36 PM vg_livecd-lv_home      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

we want now to add the hostname of the machine in the beginning of each line

first we found the hostname

```
hostname=` hostname `

echo $hostname

server_mng14
```

expected results

```
sar -p -d 1 1


server_mng14 07:16:35 PM       DEV       tps  rd_sec/s  wr_sec/s  avgrq-sz  avgqu-sz     await     svctm     %util
server_mng14 07:16:36 PM       sda     13.00      0.00    120.00      9.23      0.04      3.08      1.38      1.80
server_mng14 07:16:36 PM vg_livecd-lv_root     15.00      0.00    120.00      8.00      0.05      3.07      1.27      1.90
server_mng14 07:16:36 PM vg_livecd-lv_swap      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
server_mng14 07:16:36 PM vg_livecd-lv_home      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00      0.00
```

what we need to pipe after - `sar -p -d 1 1` in order to get the hostname of the beginning of each line?

Comment: `sar` on my system shows `Linux 4.4.38 (comp)     09/24/2019      _x86_64_        (8 CPU)` header on the top but it's missing in your example. What version of `sar` do you use?

Comment: sysstat version 10.1.5
(C) Sebastien Godard (sysstat <at> orange.fr)

Comment: Ok, I use `11.2.1.1`. Are you sure there is no header in output of `sar` or you just removed it?

Comment: I not understand why this is important because what I want is to add the hostname in the first field of the output , it could be any other command

Comment: This is important because you post incorrect input that only causes confusion and expect people to help you. And the header already contains hostname so `comp Linux 4.4.38 (comp)        09/24/2019      _x86_64_        (8 CPU)` looks weird.

Comment: Yael I'd recommend you use `hostname=$(hostname)` instead of deprecated backticks. Also, double-quote your variables when you use them, i.e. `echo "$hostname"` rather than `echo $hostname`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could run:

```
sar -p -d 1 1 | sed "s/^/$(hostname) /"
```

Comment: what in case I run the sar cli on remote machine , so how in this case I set the hostname of remote machine inside sed?

Comment: `ssh user@remote-machine 'sar -p -d 1 1 | sed "s/^/$(hostname) /"'`

Answer (score 7):

You can do:

```
sar -p -d 1 1 | sed "s,^,$(hostname) ,"
```

if you want to prepend hostname to only non-empty lines:

```
sar -p -d 1 1 | sed -E "s,^(.+),$(hostname) \1,"
```

Comment: what in case I run the sar cli on remote machine , so how in this case I set the hostname of remote machine inside sed?

Comment: How do you run it? Do you use SSH?

Comment: example - res=` ssh $remote_machine "sar -p -d 1 1"    , then echo "$res"  | ....

Comment: @yael: your example is not correct. Fix formatting.

Answer (score 2):

An awk version:

```
sar -p -d 1 1 | awk -v HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME '{print HOSTNAME " " $0}'
```

with the -v flag we set the bash $HOSTNAME variable to a variable that awk can reference in its print statement. With $0 we print the entire line

Or on ssh:

```
ssh user@remote "sar -p -d 1 1 | awk -v HOSTNAME=$HOSTNAME '{print HOSTNAME \" \" \$0}'"
```

Comment: You're missing a whitespace: `'{print HOSTNAME " " $0}'`

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing that out. I also fixed some escaping issues for the ssh command